# Linux | Upload a .tar.gz file to a FTP-Server with encryption enabled and port changed

Tags: bash, ftp, scp, script

First forward I gotta say that I'm a scripting noob and just've started to learn Linux.

I need your help with the integrated ftp-client on Linux.
I want to write a script that automaticly packs a folder (in my case the /home dir on my server) to a .tar.gz file and sends it to my ftp-server at home. Problem here is that I have changed the default ftp-port to another one.

The backup script itself is working fine but now I got stuck with using the ftp-client in Linux. Lets say my ftp-port is **12345** and my adress for the ftp is **ftp.example.com**, so I would use the command like this:

scp -P **12345** /backupdir/backup1.tar.gz backupuser@**ftp.example.com**:/

But somehow nothing happens.

Thank your for your help.

Comment: [ftp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol) and [scp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy_protocol) are two completely different things.

Answer (score 0):

```
tar cvz /home | ncftpput -P 12345 -r 5 -F -c -u ftpUsername -p ftpPassword ftpHost $FILE
```

should do the trick. `ncftpput` is in the `ncftp` package. The line should be self-explanatory; the r switch is the number of attempts to connect (redials), F is for passive mode.

`$FILE` is the variable with the desired filename. You could also specify the name manually.